# Can't go past Cloudflare's verify you are human check even after clicking the check box multiple times when using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am unable to get past this check. Even though I click it goes back to this state.
[image]

I tried using:

- Browsers data and profile so that all the history, cookie and cache is present but still
- Without using profile and data
- By running Chromium browser on using --remote-debugging-port and connecting selenium to it.
  It is failing in all 3.

If I copy the link manually in the same selenium session and paste in new tab and then click the check box it works.

```
from os import path
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/abhishek/.config/chromium/")
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"

chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                            "Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.79")
try:
    driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                    service=Service(executable_path=path.join("/home", "abhishek", "opt",
                                                              "chromedriver_linux", "chromedriver")))
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://etherscan.io")
    sleep(5)
    input_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-panel")
    input_box.click()
    sleep(1)
    input_box.send_keys("0x896463c65b70da9bbe267c2feb97ab59fc715506")
    sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.flex-fill.text-truncate").click()
    sleep(6)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "dropdownMenuBalance").click()
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 450)")
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='far fa-wallet me-1']").click()
    sleep(20)
except Exception as e:
    print("OUT", e)
    driver.close()
```

Please help

Comment: since the purpose of that capture is precisely to prevent automated access.. what are you trying to achieve in the first place.. (and why)

Comment: I am told to do this so that's why and I and trying to get data from the page.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Selenium interaction is yet of a bot and your CAPTCHAs also notice how the mouse is being moved towards the checkbox area. So you will be required to use CAPTCHA bypassers like 2captcha, anti-captcha, etc.

Comment: ooookay.. searched a lot and previously people were able to solve it by using udected_chrome and cloudscraper but nothing is working for this particluar page. Thank you.

Comment: @ABHISHEKTIWARI were you able find any working solution for this?